# How would I determine a closed form for the sum of this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I understand that this series:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} i\left(\left(\frac{1+(-1)^{i+1}}{2}\right)\sin(x) + \left(\frac{1-(-1)^{i+1}}{2}\right)\cos(x)\right)$$

Takes inputs and determines whether sin or cos is outputted. I can calculate the partial sums manually, but the question is asking me to develop a closed form formula for the above series in the form:
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} i\left(\left(\frac{1+(-1)^{i+1}}{2}\right)\sin(x) + \left(\frac{1-(-1)^{i+1}}{2}\right)\cos(x)\right) = k \cdot \sin\left(x+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)\right)$$

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: I don't see any $n$ dependence on the right-hand side, so there is probably some kind of error in transcription.

Comment: @EricTowers $k,p,q$ are unknowns, and presumably depend on $n.$

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your sequence can be expanded as follows:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} i((\dfrac{1+(-1)^{i+1}}{2})\sin(x) + (\dfrac{1-(-1)^{i+1}}{2})\cos(x))\\=\sin(x) +2\cos(x)+3\sin(x) +4\cos(x)+...+n{\rm zzz}(x)$$

Where ${\rm zzz}(x)$ is either $\sin(x)$ or $\cos(x)$, depending on $n$. From this it is clear that our sum can be written as $a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)$, where $a$ and $b$ are the sums of odd and even numbers up to and including $n$. Thus:

$$a=\sum_{i=1}^{\lceil n/2\rceil}2i-1=\left\lceil \frac{n}{2}\right\rceil^2$$

$$b=\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}2i=\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor^2+\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor$$

Then you can transform it into the form $r\sin(x+\phi)$ with the following relations:

$$r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
$$\phi=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-b}{a}\right)$$

Comment: So then would $\phi = tan^{-1}\bigg(\dfrac{b}{a}\bigg)$ be the closed form equation? I don't think we've learned that formula yet in class, so would is that the only way to state the answer?

Comment: @Wurner I'm not 100% certain on the values in the arctan (I'm used to transforming to cos) but your $k,p,q$ correspond to my $r,b,a$ respectively.

Comment: @Wurner redid my analysis for $\phi$, turns out $p=-b$.

Comment: So could I simply substitute the values of $b$ and $a$, and theoretically, it should give me the sum of any nth term?

Comment: It should, yes.

Comment: sorry for asking this so late, but did you use the harmonic addition theorem to derive your answer? If so, how did you apply it to this situation?

Comment: @Wurner I'm not really familiar with the name "harmonic addition theorem". I essentially used a modified version of triangular numbers. If you think that name applies to what I did, then by all means make that connection. It might even lead to an easier derivation than what I did.

Comment: Yes, but I believe your answer would only work if we derive for cos. For sin, it's the same equation but instead of $\tan{^-1}\bigg(\dfrac{-b}{a}\bigg)$, it's simply $\tan{^-1}\bigg(\dfrac{a}{b}\bigg)$